# Excel VBA: Run-time error '13'': type mismatch due to unrecognized date formats

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a very simple VBA code to identify periods between dates, however it seems Excel is not recognizing the cells as dates and generating a type mismatch error when I run the macro, could you please help resolveingthe issue? Many thanks in advance.

[image: date cells]

```
Sub datesexcelvba()

Dim mydate1 As Date
Dim mydate2 As Long
Dim datetoday1 As Date
Dim datetoday2 As Long

Dim x As Long
lastrow = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For x = 8 To lastrow

mydate1 = Cells(x, 10).Value
mydate2 = mydate1

Cells(x, 25).Value = mydate2

datetoday1 = Date
datetoday2 = datetoday1

Cells(x, 20).Value = datetoday2

If mydate2 - datetoday2 = 3 Then
    
    Cells(x, 29) = "yes"
    Cells(x, 29).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Cells(x, 29).Font.ColorIndex = 2
    Cells(x, 29).Font.Bold = True
    Cells(x, 30).Value = mydate2 - datetoday2
End If
Next
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! `mydate1` is of type `Date` and yet `Cells(x, 10).value` is a string. Therefore, if the implicit conversion is not possible (probably if the locales are not compatible), the code will fail, raising a type mismatch error. Do you know which line causes the problem?

Comment: Hi Victor,
Thanks for your reply.

This is the line causing the error >> mydate1 = Cells(x, 10).Value

My regional settings are set to English (United States) however I am in the Netherlands.

Format of the cells is set to English(United States) as well.

Comment: Try changing that to `mydate1 = CDate(Cells(x, 10))` to switch to explicit conversion.

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same outcome :(

Comment: Instead of `Cells(x, 10).Value` try `DateValue(Cells(x, 10))`

Comment: Have you explicitly formatted the cells themselves as `Date` in excel? Judging from what I see in the pic it seems like you haven't. Select cell>CTRL+1>Category>Date.

Comment: Yes, the cells are formatted as dates and aligned with the regional settings: English (United States).

Datevalue(Cells(x, 10)) is giving the same error..
And FYI - these dates are not being imported from any other source, they are typed directly in the excel file

Comment: Have you attempted to use `dateArray=Split(.Cells(x,y),"/")` then use the values in each part of the array to assign year, month, and day?

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/299437/52365

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pasting comment as an answer, as I believe it should resolve your issue of having a string being converted to a date.

---

You can use the function `Split()` in VBA to utilize each part of the string, knowing it has three (3) parts: a year, a month, and a day.

The below code changes the date string in `Cells(1,1)` and outputs a serial date in `Cells(1,2)`:

```
Option Explicit

Sub convertDateStringToDateSerial()
    With Sheets(1)
        Dim dateString As String
        dateString = .Cells(1, 1).Value
        'can add an if-statement to check for "/" presence, if needed
        Dim dateArray As Variant
        dateArray = Split(dateString, "/")
        Dim dateYear As Long
        dateYear = dateArray(2)
        Dim dateMonth As Long
        dateMonth = dateArray(0)
        Dim dateDay As Long
        dateDay = dateArray(1)
        .Cells(1, 2).Value = DateSerial(dateYear, dateMonth, dateDay)
    End With
End Sub
```

The input and output are:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Cyril, this solution solved the problem!